# Local Cancellation in Real Hardy Space

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I want to show the following asymtotic estimate in Hardy space over $\mathbb{R}^n$: Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show the function
$$
f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{B(0,1)}-\mathbb{1}_{B(a,1)}
$$
is asymtotic to $\ln|a|$; that is,
$$
||f||_{\mathcal{H}^1}\sim \ln|a|
$$
The definitions we use here is the following:
If $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(B(0,1))$, then there is a maximal operator
$$
M_\varphi(f)(x)=\sup_t |\varphi_t*f| = \sup \frac{1}{t^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi\left(\frac{x-y}{t}\right)
f(y)dy
$$
where $\varphi_t:=\varphi(x/t)/t^n$ and $\varphi$ satisfies
$$
\int_{B(0,1)}\varphi = 1, \varphi\geq 0,\mbox{ and }\varphi = 1/\mathcal{L}(B(0,1))\;\forall x\in B(0,1/2)
$$
The Hardy norm of $f$ is defined to be the $L^1$-norm of this maximal operator evaluated at $f$.

It can be shown that $||f||_{\mathcal{H}^1}/\ln|a|$ is certainly bounded by showing $M_\varphi(f)(x)\geq c|x|^{-n}$, however the upper bound is the difficulty.

Comment: Do you mean $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, I'll correct this.